# How can I add an endpoint with address created by id and querystring?

Tags: aiohttp

with aiohttp I would like to create a GET endpoint, where in the url is entered the id I need and also a querystring, I would like that retrieve the image in the db `document_id` and also the format, querystring `type`

```py
# app/http/routes/v1/variation.py

routes = [
    get(f"/{version}/{path}/download/{{document_id}}/{{type}}", readvariationController.handle)
]
```

```py
# app/http/routes/v1/__init__.py
from app.http.routes.v1.variation import routes as variation_routes

routes = variation_routes
```

```py
# __main__

app = web.Application()

app.add_routes(routes)
```

I have no problem with other "simpler" endpoints, but I can't get a more complex endpoint to work, what am I doing wrong?

**It returns an error 405**

EDIT:
What I would like to have is this

```
http://localhost:3099/v1/storage/download/112/?type=mini
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved:

```py
self.__request: Request = request
# get document_id
self.__request.match_info.get("document_id", None)

# and finally get querystring
self.__request.rel_url.query['type']
```